# Keep URL request but adjust server path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I achieve the following:

I have two domains hosted within the same web root path on the server. Usually php manages my HTTP_Hosts dynamically. Related to my question I am using the directory lisings function of apache. Each Request for /peter/ should point effectively to a different directory.

```
example.com/peter/  ->  /peter_example.com/
xamplee.com/peter/  ->  /peter_xamplee.com/
```

The Url should always contain /peter/ but in effect link to the respective real path which I'd like to have hidden.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after getting into **regex** and into **mode_rewrite** the hard way I can come up with the solution all by myself:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Force adding a trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^peter/(.*)$ /peter_example\.com/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xamplee\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^peter/(.*)$ /peter_xamplee\.com/$1 [NC,L]
```